# Can i use the "app_code" folder in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Is the app_code folder used in asp.net also available in net. core?

If I can't use it, is there any other way I can compile it into folders at runtime?

Answer (score -1):

You can name the folder as "app_code" in .net core application.

If you want to copy the "app_code" folder when publish the application, try to set the file's "CopyToPublishDirectory" property to "Always" (open the app_code folder, right click the file and select the "Properties" option, then change the "CopyToPublishDirectory" property to "Always").

Besides, you could also change the property's value from the applicaion .csproj file, using the following code:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="app_core\testclass.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Compile> 
 </ItemGroup>
```